# How to detect iframe load failure in an ionic application

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my ionic application I need to show external website which I show in an iFrame.
 While the website is fetched and loaded I show loading spinner. I want to hide it once the iframe/website is loaded and it it fails then I need to show a button saying "Launch in an external browser". So the question is how to check if iframe website load is failed in an IONIC app.